# Is it possible to disable Minimum Performance Percentage or Low Frequency Mode?

Tags: laptop, performance, power

I have a Dell Inspiron 3551 going on 8 years old laptop.
Just recently I accidentally caught the AC cord and damaged the tip of the cord as well as the socket, which resulted in not being able to move the laptop or AC cord when plugged in, because if I do the laptop loses power and switches off.

Well the bigger issue is that, when I turn it back on, I get 23% of my CPU power only which results in 0.50 GHz.

Is there a way to switch it off?
Any additional information needed, I will provide!

Thank You very much in advance!

Edit:
My laptop works fine, until i accidentally move it, then because of fragile AC adapter connection, it switches off, which is understandable, but when i power it back on, it runs in Low Frequency Mode until i shut it down, start up again - runs full power!

Comment: Sounds like the battery needs replacing as well as the power socket. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: I have no battery installed, because this is not the original AC adapter and they weren't compatible together, so I removed the battery and use only AC

Comment: Then what better do you expect? The battery is there to power the laptop. The charger is to charge the battery. The battery is designed for high power output when required, the charger is not. Therefore, running without the battery will make the computer do its best to keep power consumption down, so it doesn't crash. Solution - get a new battery & a proper charger & get the socket fixed.

Comment: I think You are misunderstanding my issue. The laptop works fine as it is, BUT when the AC tip moves in the socket and it suddenly switches off, THEN when i switch it on, it uses Low Frequency Mode. I fix it by either pressing power button for 5 seconds to power it down or just power it down from start menu. then I boot up and it works as it is supposed to. So my question is how can i avoid Laptop booting in LFM right away?

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding. You have a cobbled-together power supply with a broken socket & no battery. What do you expect but random behaviour. Get it fixed. You seem to be looking for a solution that requires more duck tape & Heath Robinson tactics, I'm offering one that needs less.

Comment: It is not random.